# Making a PythonCard File Dialog single select?

Tags: python, pythoncard

I'm working on a python application and have chosen to build the gui with PythonCard.  I have need to have the user select a file to open, and in the context, selecting more than 1 file doesn't make sense.  I can successfully create a file dioalog with

```
dialog.fileDialog(self, 'Open Input File', '', '')
```

And I would imagine I need to use the optional style parameter in order to get a sinlge select dialog, but I can't find an example or documentation of what I need to pass to the fifth param in order to get a single select file dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the last line to wx.OPEN - that should be it. It seems that PythonCard specifies a dialog's main style as wx.OPEN | wx.MULTIPLE, so overriding it to just open should do the trick.

Comment: this wordked.  its also worth noting that the style parameter is the 6th param, not the 5th.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reference for PythonCard dialogs:
[pythoncard.sourceforge.net/dialogs](http://pythoncard.sourceforge.net/dialogs/index.html)

It provides an explanation of the arguments for each dialog type along with examples.